# UNIX scripting problem

Tags: bash

I have to write a script where i need to show the sum of entered numbers and the biggest & smallest number among them. I am using array. I have solved this with normal way. but when i am using array i am getting sum, biggest number but can get the lowest number.I understand its because of my if logic for smallest number.

my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
small=0
big=0

echo "Please enter the number"

while(( n != -99 ));
 do
        read -a n
        arr=${#n[@]}
     for((i=0;i<$arr;i++))do
     if [ ${n[$i]} -eq -99 ]; then
        break
     elif [ ${n[$i]} -ne -99 ]; then
     sum=$((sum + n[$i]))

     if [ ${n[$i]} -gt $big ]; then
     big=${n[i]}

    elif [ ${n[$i]} -le $small ]; then
     small=${n[i]}
    fi
   fi
    done
 done

echo "Sum: $sum"
echo "Highest: $big"
echo "Lowest:  $small"
```

output:

```
Please enter the number
12
13
14
-99
Sum: 39
Highest: 14
Lowest:  0
```

Comment: You're missing a `$` before some of your `i` variables.  Also get into the habit of always quoting your variables even if you think they don't need it.

Comment: @jimmij thanks... i tried with higher value.. but i got that same value which i have stored in small variable at first. for example, if initialize small=100 then i got lowest output 100 no matter what ever i have inserted less than hundred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me and I believe it is what you are trying to accomplish:

```
#! /bin/bash - 
NUM_SUM=0
NUM_LARGE=0
echo  "Please enter the numbers (-99 to exit):"

while [[ "$THIS_NUM" -ne '-99' ]]; do
    read -a THIS_NUM
    if [[ "$THIS_NUM" -ne '-99' ]]; then
        THIS_ARRAY+=("$THIS_NUM")
    fi
done
NUM_SMALL="${THIS_ARRAY[0]}"
for NUM in "${THIS_ARRAY[@]}"; do
    NUM_SUM=$((${NUM_SUM}+${NUM}))
    if [[ "$NUM" -gt "$NUM_LARGE" ]]; then
        NUM_LARGE="$NUM"
    elif [[ "$NUM" -lt "$NUM_SMALL" ]]; then
        NUM_SMALL="$NUM"
    fi
done
cat <<EOF
Summary:    $NUM_SUM
High Num:   $NUM_LARGE
Low Num:    $NUM_SMALL
EOF
```

I have this script ignoring the `-99` input which I'm guessing you are only using as a way to exit the loop?  With your input numbers I get the following output:

```
Please enter the numbers:
12
13
14
-99
Summary:    39
High Num:   14
Low Num:    12
```

Comment: yes  -99 sentinel value to exit the loop...thanks a lot, i have found where i did the mistake...works 100%.it on the while loop for me... great man..you are a legend!!!!